# How to get a street map from location point and distance

Tags: shapefile, extents

I would like to find a way to get the map giving a location point (center point) and a distance.

For example, I would like to get the image map of a place with a squared area of N, S, E, W each 525 m from location point 51.05660 N, 3.721500 E.

I would like to download, if possible, the image generated of this zone in png, eps or shapefile.

Regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**OpenStreetMap** can do this to a certain point

1. You add your lat/lng in and set the scale
2. Click Export Map
3. Select Format (PNG,JPEG,SVG,PDF)
4. Download the file.

A route for shapefile is either use the Geofabrik Downloads to the left (below Export Box)
or use SVG as an option and then use Illustator (or inkscape) to convert the svg to dxf and load into QGIS and convert to shapefile.

[image]

Link to the location and image (you can zoom in more)
https://www.openstreetmap.org/#map=10/51.0867/3.4868

Comment: Thank for comment. In the export left side of the window, it is possible to select the limits of the bounding box of the map. Is it possible to compute those latitudes and longitudes giving the center location coordinate and a distance? I have to overlay to the map an image that was obtained this way and that will give colors to the streets and the two should match.

Comment: with the overpass api yes - but there are osm server file size limits you may run into.